# unorderable types error when importing sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I installed numpy(1.12.0b1), Scipy(0.18) on windows. I also installed sci-kit as well. When i wrote "import sklearn" in python console, it gives an error like this: 
if np_version < (1, 12, 0):
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
What will be the issue?

Comment: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7898

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is out on the version number, so maybe you could try to revise `fixs.py` in the `sklearn` folder. Add these script after the `try` in line 32:

```
if not (x.isdigit()):
    x='0'
```

so your codes will be:

```
def _parse_version(version_string):
version = []
for x in version_string.split('.'):
    try:
        if not (x.isdigit()):
            x='0'
        version.append(int(x))
        #print(x)
    except ValueError:
        # x may be of the form dev-1ea1592
        version.append(x)
return tuple(version)
```

Comment: Please don't post code as images, use the code formatting tool instead.