# unorderable types: str() < int()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

i was designing a basic spam classifier program (**python 3**) using pandas, numpy and sklearn but i am getting this error and not able to identify where. I tried to see datatypes of different variables but didn't find the location. (ham = not spam). Input files has to do nothing with this error, as its working with python 2.7
Either its packages/modules compatibility or data type casting error.

```
import os
import io
import numpy
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

def readFiles(path):
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
            path = os.path.join(root, filename)

            inBody = False
            lines = []
            f = io.open(path, 'r', encoding='latin1')
            for line in f:
                if inBody:
                    lines.append(line)
                elif line == '\n':
                    inBody = True
            f.close()
            message = '\n'.join(lines)
            yield path, message


def dataFrameFromDirectory(path, classification):
    rows = []
    index = []
    for filename, message in readFiles(path):
        rows.append({'message': message, 'class': classification})
        index.append(filename)

    return DataFrame(rows, index=index)

data = DataFrame({'message': [], 'class': []})

data = data.append(dataFrameFromDirectory('D:/emails/spam', 'spam'))
data = data.append(dataFrameFromDirectory('D:/emails/ham', 'ham'))
```

Stack Trace from ipython NoteBook:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-555887356cc2> in <module>()
      3 import numpy
      4 from pandas import DataFrame
----> 5 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
      6 from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
      7 

c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>()
     55 else:
     56     from . import __check_build
---> 57     from .base import clone
     58     __check_build  # avoid flakes unused variable error
     59 

c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>()
     10 from scipy import sparse
     11 from .externals import six
---> 12 from .utils.fixes import signature
     13 from .utils.deprecation import deprecated
     14 from .exceptions import ChangedBehaviorWarning as _ChangedBehaviorWarning

c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>()
      9 
     10 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
---> 11 from .validation import (as_float_array,
     12                          assert_all_finite,
     13                          check_random_state, column_or_1d, check_array,

c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in <module>()
     16 
     17 from ..externals import six
---> 18 from ..utils.fixes import signature
     19 from .deprecation import deprecated
     20 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning as _DataConversionWarning

c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py in <module>()
    404 
    405 
--> 406 if np_version < (1, 12, 0):
    407     class MaskedArray(np.ma.MaskedArray):
    408         # Before numpy 1.12, np.ma.MaskedArray object is not picklable

TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

Comment: You should post the full error you got.

Comment: post the stack-trace.

Comment: Try designing a [mcve]. We don't have your data files either, so we can't run your code to reproduce your error.

Comment: If you're new to python, you should learn the basics of the language before using advanced frameworks such as sklearn. That might help debugging errors.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga have updated error trace from ipython notebook.

Comment: @Praveen how to provide data files? I believe its not possible...

Comment: @AndrasDeak everyone starts somewhere . i learned basic python and then jumped in to this. #respect

Comment: I suspect a mismatch in package versions.  Something, maybe `numpy`, or `scipy` is older than what `sklearn` and/or `pandas` expects.  The error is in an `sklearn` import, not in your own code.

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824903/unorderable-types-error-when-importing-sklearn#comment68868382_40824903)? cc @hpaulj

Comment: So a beta numpy is giving the `sklearn` version check problems.

Comment: Hi i dont know why people down-voted it and it went on-hold. Instead of educating others , the learned people down-votes new people who are trying to learn things. Having thousands of Reputations and Badges are of no worth not being educator. If my question is not proper formatted or has less information, these learned people should ask for specific information instead of negative reps.

Though, i found solution as i commented in below answer, Thanks to @hpaulj .

Comment: @KARANJ look at the first three comments on your post, which were posted *2 hours* before you changed anything in your question. How is that not "asking for specific information"? The lesson is if you ask a question, stick around for half an hour so that you can put it into shape before it gets downvoted. Until your question is fixed, it's low-quality, and deserves the downvotes.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Ok i got the idea, i made the changes according to those comments and turns out that what my question was right and good-quality after doing edit. So someone should remove those down votes and remove hold on it. How it works.. Thanks for help on this.. :)

Comment: @KARANJ I agree, *after* your edit it's an answerable question. Unfortunately, people rarely stick around to see if their downvotes should be removed (hence my suggestion to stick around for a while after posting your question). For what it's worth, your question has two reopen votes, one of them mine. In the mean time, in case hpaulj's answer solved your problem, you should consider marking it as accepted (it will indicate that the question no longer needs an answer, and it will give reputation to both of you).

Comment: Such an error happens when you try to compare an int and a string in python 3 (try `1 < 'a'` or `sorted([1, 'a'])`). In python 2, ints and strings are comparable so it doesn't raise. I can see now that it is your numpy version which is not an int.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thanks Sir,.. want to connect with you on LinkedIn.. Will help me in my learning path of Machine learning

Comment: @KARANJ thank you, but it won't help you: I don't have anything to do with machine learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With my collection of versions - relatively recent, but not cutting edge:

```
In [509]: import sklearn
In [510]: sklearn.__version__
Out[510]: '0.17'
In [511]: np.__version__
Out[511]: '1.11.2'
In [512]: sklearn.utils.fixes._parse_version(np.__version__)
Out[512]: (1, 11, 2)
In [513]: sklearn.utils.fixes._parse_version(np.__version__)<(1,12,0)
Out[513]: True
```

The last step is comparing one tuple, derived from the `np.__version__` string, with another.

I'd suggest importing, and printing, to the extent possible:

```
np.__version__
scipy.__version__
sys.version
scklearn.__version__
```

Following Andras link, the problem is the `numpy` version number.  If numpy is a new beta version, the `0b1` part of the version number gives this test problems.

```
In [517]: sklearn.utils.fixes._parse_version('1.12.0b1')<(1,12,0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-517-a2d159f6d08a> in <module>()
----> 1 sklearn.utils.fixes._parse_version('1.12.0b1')<(1,12,0)

TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

The simplest solution, if possible, to go back to a regular numpy release (something like '1.11.2'), rather than a beta.

The negative votes for the OP are unfair if this is indeed a numpy/sklearn version issue.

Comment: After some research and help from hpaulj it worked out that i had numpy1.12.0rc1 was installed.
So i uninstalled it and downloaded 1.11.3+mkl pre-compiled and installed it. Worked !! THanks @hpaulj

Comment: I'd generally agree with the "downvotes are unfair to poor OP" sentiment, but [the question for its first 2 hours](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41292301/3) didn't contain a traceback, and it was very unclear where the error was coming from. The code was much more than an MCVE, and reading through it I couldn't find where the problem could come from. (Curiously, I didn't actually downvote the question.)

Comment: A whole 2 hours!  I started to answer at 3, so didn't see how horrible that initial version was.  Since people post from around the world, and on different schedules I try to be patient.